# Что делат такая запись при использовании gcc __attribute__ ((format (n, f, e)))?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Что делат такая запись при использовании gcc

```
 __attribute__ ((format (n, f, e)))
```

Comment: Включает для вашей функции проверку аргументов (варнинги) как для `printf`. Что писать вместо `n`, `f`, `e` - смотреть в мануале на гцц...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот атрибут заставляет компилятор проверять, что предоставленные аргументы имеют правильный формат для определяемой функции использующей функции форматирования, где есть параметр со строкой форматирования и есть параметр принимающий аргументы со значениями форматирующими эту строку.

Например, у Вас есть функция:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

__attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 5)))
void print_object_info(void* obj, const char* format, int flags, int e, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);

  vprintf(format, args);

  va_end(args);
}
```

Здесь компилятор удостоверится, что второй параметр определённой функции `const char* format` является *форматируемой строкой* и передаётся как аргумент *форматируемой строки* в *функцию форматирования*, а аргументы начиная с пятого (`...`) используются как аргументы подставляемые в форматирование. В противном случае выдаст ошибку:

```
source.c:11:1: error: args to be formatted is not ‘...’
{
```

Подробнее можно прочитать в документации GCC [здесь](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html).